# Baseboard heat not bringing room to temperature - hot water, 1 of 4 zones, Carlin burner, bell and gossett circulators, Weil Mcclain boiler

Tags: baseboard, temperature

Circulator runs continuously, baseboard runs warm, not hot as before. Room doesn't reach temperature

Comment: Is this problem new?  The room stayed warm before or has always been cold?

Comment: What does the pressure part of the gauge on the boiler show? Typically one gauge, two needles, one for pressure, one for temperature. Could be two separate gauges. Should be there by code one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to find bleeder valves and let air out of this loop, or the circulator's gone bad. It's only 1 of 4 zones affected, so it can't be the boiler not heating adequately, so that points to poor circulation. Trapped air does that, a circulator that's not working right also does that.

2% edge case might be low system pressure and it's the highest loop.

The 0.1% edge case would be if someone messed with the balancing valves. But those are generally made to require some effort and tools to mess with, not handy valve handles you can inadvertently turn.